# Multiple sonarRunner tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I'm moving from Eclipse/Ant to AndroidStudio/Gradle.
In Ant, I had multiple sonar related tasks. Eg. one using a profile that mainly checked performance issues, and another one that did a complete check.

In Gradle, I can create a (single?) sonarRunner task like

```
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        ...
        property "sonar.profile",  "Performance"
        ...
    }
}
```

But I also want to have a second `sonarRunner` task with a different `sonar.profile` property (and probably also different `projectKey/projectName/...`)

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create another task of type `SonarRunner`. the tricky part is to fill the sonarProperties property (a map with all the sonar related properties. the default sonarRunner task is automatically configured, but you might be able to use these default properties

```
task("sonarRunnerPerformance", SonarRunner){
    // configure sonarProperties manually
    sonarProperties = tasks.sonnarRunner.sonarProperties

    //overwrite sonar profile property
    sonarProperties << ["sonar.profile":"Performance"]
}
```

cheers,
René

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This results in "Gradle DSL method not found: 'task()'"    . 

When I rewrite it as 
task sonarRunnerPerformance(type: SonarRunner){
    // configure sonarProperties manually
    sonarProperties = tasks.sonarRunner.sonarProperties
    //overwrite sonar profile property
    sonarProperties << ["sonar.profile":"Performance"]
} 
this results in Error:(312, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'sonarProperties' on task ':twintv:sonarRunnerPerformance'.